# Ubuntu 18.04 thunderbolt: clicked "forget this device" now, how do I get it back?

Tags: 18.04, thunderbolt

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and my external 10G NIC wasn't working correctly so I clicked "forget this device" in Settings --> Thunderbolt. Now I want to get it back. How can I reset the list of "forgotten devices" or initiate a rescan? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out a solution?